# Magento/php: adding product to cart with custom details and price

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart, addtocart

(Magento 1.9) I created a form to be able to customize a product and generate a preview sketch of what the end result would look like with a cost (this was done outside of Magento as an individual program). Now I integrated this into a Magento page in a custom frontend template.

Now I am trying to add this to the cart. Considering each customer might order several versions of the product, each with its unique details, I was experimenting with creating a new simple product for each version (it seems that if I try to add them as the same product, magento groups them together with the same price), before adding it to the cart. However, I am having trouble actually adding the product into the cart. This is my code so far for adding to cart:

```
<?php 
// Mage init
require_once Mage::getBaseDir() . '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();


// Add a product with custom options    
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku('testsku17'));

$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $request);  // This line tends to break my code regularly (meaning everything halts when I leave it in)

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();

echo "added to cart <br>";
?>
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
// Mage init
include_once dirname(__FILE__). '/app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();


// Add a product with custom options
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('acj005'));

$param = array(
    'qty' => 1
);

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($product, $request);  // This line tends to break my code regularly (meaning everything halts when I leave it in)

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();

echo "added to cart 
";
```

Comment: This adds the product to cart, but every instance is a copy of the default. I need each instance to be separate with different settings (eg. price, size, etc) and be able to add a link or comments visible from the back-end....  Also, when I open the cart, it adds an instance of the product (ie. if I added a quantity of 3, when I open the cart I will have 4)

Answer (score 0):

If you want add product to cart with custom options then you can try the below code:

```
Mage::init('default');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  
// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 
// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();
$productid=1;
$qty=1;
$options = array("1"=>"test","2"=>"44");
// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => $qty,
    'options' =>$options 
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $request);

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();
```

Comment: It did not work. Is there something that needs to be previously configured for your code to work? What is it? I thought the only thing I needed was a product with ID=1. But I have that and when I ran your code, the page broke.... (meaning that the layout gets all screwy and everything I print/echo before the code now does not show)